# How add font within Echo php in old script?

Tags: php

Please I have an old code, and I need format it with google font or other fonts, 
I was try some statement but not work, 
Please help!

-------------- The Code --------------

```html
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
<?php
include "inc/config.inc.php";
?>
<table width="100%" dir="rtl">

<?php
     $query = "SELECT person_id, name, DATE_FORMAT(updated, ".$datefmt.") AS ddate, suffix FROM ".$tblprefix."people";
     if ($_SESSION["id"] == 0)
      $query .= " WHERE date_of_birth < '".$restrictdate."'";
     $query .= " ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 0,5";
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die($err_changed);
     $i = 0;
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      if ($i == 0 || fmod($i, 2) == 0)
       $class = "tbl_odd";
      else
       $class = "tbl_even";
?>
     <tr>
      <td class="<?php echo $class; ?>" align="right"><li><a target="_blank" href="people.php?person=<?php echo '<style = "font-color: #ff0000"> $row["person_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]." ".$row["suffix"]; ?></a></td>
      
<!-- <td class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $row["ddate"]; ?></td> -->
     </tr>
<?php
      $i++;
     }
     mysql_free_result($result);

?>
    </table>
```

Comment: How exactly have you tried to add the style? Styling is done with CSS, not PHP - but PHP can print the string which effectively makes the CSS or classes if you need it to be conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use alternate styling for odd and even rows, you can do that with plain CSS using the :odd or :even selectors.